# Find the value of $VN$ in Hexagon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

He asked for $ VN $ and said that you have $ 2 $ squares and a regular hexagon, in addition to the hexagon side being $ 1 $.

The only thing I found out here was that the triangles are equilateral $ \frac {VNS} {SUM} $

What can I do?

Comment: Who asked for $VN$? What is the source of the question?

Comment: Please use the fact that $BC = ?$ and $\angle RBC = \angle RCB = ?$.

Comment: @MathLover This is the question of the question. What is that fact?

Comment: $CDVU$ does not look like a square but if it is then we can proceed. You know $BC = 1$, right? You know the angles I mentioned earlier to be $30^0$ too, yes? Does that help you to proceed?

Comment: Can you please disclose the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have spotted the equilateral triangles, note that:
$$\measuredangle UMB=\measuredangle MBC \implies \bigtriangleup MUR \sim \bigtriangleup BCR$$
Both of these triangles are $120°-30°-30°$ triangles, so the longer side is $√3$ times the shorter sides.

You can find $MR$ via:
$$MR=AB-BR$$
Applying similarity:

$$(1-1/√3)/(1/√3)=UM/1 \implies UM=√3-1$$

Since both are equilateral triangles:

$$VN=1-(√3-1)=2-√3$$